# jQuery loop over JSON result from AJAX Success?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

On the jQuery AJAX success callback I want to loop over the results of the object.     This is an example of how the response looks in Firebug.

```
[
 {"TEST1":45,"TEST2":23,"TEST3":"DATA1"},
 {"TEST1":46,"TEST2":24,"TEST3":"DATA2"},
 {"TEST1":47,"TEST2":25,"TEST3":"DATA3"}
]
```

How can I loop over the results so that I would have access to each of the elements?
I have tried something like below but this does not seem to be working.

```
jQuery.each(data, function(index, itemData) {
  // itemData.TEST1
  // itemData.TEST2
  // itemData.TEST3
});
```

Comment: This should work. Are you sure that's exactly the same code and the same data?

Answer (score 274, accepted):

you can remove the outer loop and replace `this` with `data.data`:

```
$.each(data.data, function(k, v) {
    /// do stuff
});
```

You were close:

```
$.each(data, function() {
  $.each(this, function(k, v) {
    /// do stuff
  });
});
```

You have an array of objects/maps so the outer loop iterates over those. The inner loop iterates over the properties on each object element.

Comment: The first loop is for a "category" while a loop within that is for an "attribute." How else is that done?

Comment: What if you want to work with the object element rather than its properties? Why doesn't @aherrick's loop in the question work?

Comment: If this looping is used in a separate function use `$(data)` instead of `data`, otherwise the variable `k` always returns 0.

Comment: Could someone explain the variables k & v that are passed to the second function?

Comment: @BrentConnor in this case k&v represent the key & value of the array being   cycled through. Read up on jquery .each() function

Comment: I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '188' in`

Answer (score 85):

You can also use the [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function:

```
    $.getJSON('/your/script.php', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index) {
            alert(data[index].TEST1);
            alert(data[index].TEST2);
        });
    });
```

This is really just a rewording of ifesdjeen's answer, but I thought it might be helpful to people.

Comment: This helped. For some reason I couldn't get @cletus 's answer to work but this did. Not sure what the grand mystery about jQuery is but simple code does not always work as you expect it to.

Answer (score 42):

If you use Fire Fox, just open up a console (use F12 key) and try out this:

```
var a = [
 {"TEST1":45,"TEST2":23,"TEST3":"DATA1"},
 {"TEST1":46,"TEST2":24,"TEST3":"DATA2"},
 {"TEST1":47,"TEST2":25,"TEST3":"DATA3"}
];

$.each (a, function (bb) {
    console.log (bb);
    console.log (a[bb]);
    console.log (a[bb].TEST1);
});
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 19):

For anyone else stuck with this, it's probably not working because the ajax call is interpreting your returned data as text - i.e. it's not yet a JSON object.

You can convert it to a JSON object by manually using the parseJSON command or simply adding the dataType: 'json' property to your ajax call. e.g.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
    data: data, 
    dataType: 'json', // ** ensure you add this line **
    success: function(data) {
        jQuery.each(data, function(index, item) {
            //now you can access properties using dot notation
        });
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("some error");
    }
});
```

Comment: This is giving me "data is undefined".

Comment: You should use your own variable that stores the data you are passing to the url. If your data variable is called mydata then use data: mydata

Comment: Ah. Got it now. Thanks.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '188' in` getting that error.

Answer (score 15):

Access the json array like you would any other array.

```
for(var i =0;i < itemData.length-1;i++)
{
  var item = itemData[i];
  alert(item.Test1 + item.Test2 + item.Test3);
}
```

Comment: old question, but how could you loop through json keys without knowing the names... like Test1, Test2, ext...

Comment: @BarclayVision You just use the key as a number. The first key is `[0]`, the next `[1]`, and so on.

Comment: can we use another ajax call inside this for loop? If yes then Please tell me How?

Answer (score 5):

This is what I came up with to easily view all data values:

```js
var dataItems = "";
$.each(data, function (index, itemData) {
    dataItems += index + ": " + itemData + "\n";
});
console.log(dataItems);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try **jQuery.map** function, works pretty well with maps.

```js
var mapArray = {
  "lastName": "Last Name cannot be null!",
  "email": "Email cannot be null!",
  "firstName": "First Name cannot be null!"
};

$.map(mapArray, function(val, key) {
  alert("Value is :" + val);
  alert("key is :" + key);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want alert, that is u want html, then do this

```
...
    $.each(data, function(index) {
        $("#pr_result").append(data[index].dbcolumn);
    });
...
```

NOTE: use "append" not "html" else the last result is what you will be seeing on your html view

then your html code should look like this

```
...
<div id="pr_result"></div>
...
```

You can also style (add class) the div in the jquery before it renders as html

Answer (score 2):

I use .map for foreach. For example

```
success: function(data) {
  let dataItems = JSON.parse(data)
  dataItems = dataItems.map((item) => {
    return $(`<article>
                <h2>${item.post_title}</h2>
                <p>${item.post_excerpt}</p>
              </article>`)
  })
},
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the short method of JQuery ajax call function as shown below, the returned data needs to be interpreted as a json object for you to be able to loop through.

```
$.get('url', function(data, statusText, xheader){
 // your code within the success callback
  var data = $.parseJSON(data);
  $.each(data, function(i){
         console.log(data[i]);
      })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I am partial to ES2015 arrow function for finding values in an array

```
const result = data.find(x=> x.TEST1 === '46');
```

Checkout Array.prototype.find() [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 0):

`$each` will work.. Another option is [jQuery Ajax Callback for array result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683263/jquery-ajax-callback-for-array-result)

```
function displayResultForLog(result) {
  if (result.hasOwnProperty("d")) {
    result = result.d
  }

  if (result !== undefined && result != null) {
    if (result.hasOwnProperty('length')) {
      if (result.length >= 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          var sentDate = result[i];
        }
      } else {
        $(requiredTable).append('Length is 0');
      }
    } else {
      $(requiredTable).append('Length is not available.');
    }

  } else {
    $(requiredTable).append('Result is null.');
  }
}
```