# Loop JSON response after ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, callback

Sorry this is a duplicate  from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733314/jquery-loop-over-json-result-from-ajax-success) asked in SO but I'm new to this so I would like to know how to do it?

This is my ajax call:

```
  $("#btnprocess").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetFilenames",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d[0]);
                        alert(response.d[1]);
                      }
                });
  });
```

Individually I'm able to get the response but I need to loop them.

Can anyone say me how do I do this?

Comment: @xander-that dosent depend on how many points you gain it's a matter of learning something new

Comment: @all-Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do;

```
for (var i=0; i<response.d.length; i++) {
 alert(response.d[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `$.each()`.

```
$.each(response.d, function(key, value) {
    //For example
    console.log(key + value)
})
```

Look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to learn about it. (**EDIT**: Or [here](http://tutsplus.com/lesson/each-and-templating/) - it's a video tutorial if you prefer that.)

Answer (score 7):

if `response.d` is an array you could place it in a for loop like so:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++ ) {
    // do action here
}
```

This method is preferred over the jQuery `$.each()` function due to its speedier nature. Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martinaglv/NcRsV/) for a comparison of `for` vs `$.each()`.