# Ajax success function returning [object, object]

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm very new to AJAX calls - poked around the web for a few tutorials but still not quite getting successful at it.

The input field has an assigned ID of "idkey". The script is as follow:

```
$(document).on("keyup.autocomplete", "#idkey", function(){ 
    var query = "q=" + $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: query,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                content = data[i].IDKey;
                content += "<br>";
                $(content).appendTo("#output");
                // updateListing(data[x]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

On the server side, the api.php has an output of:

```
[{"IDKey":"30000001"},{"IDKey":"30000002"},{"IDKey":"30000004"}]
```

I am not sure why the `alert(data)` would return `[object Object], [object Object], [object Object]`. Any clue to why this is happening?

p/s: The php file has a header set to `Content-Type: application/json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json response is an array of 3 objects . That's the reason you are seeing the alert as an object..

Try `alert(data[0].IDKey)` .. It should give you 30000001

To see the data try console.log or place the alert inside for loop

```
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    alert(data[i].IDKey);
 }

$.each(data, function(i, value) {
   console.log('Value of '+ i +' is : ' + value);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer - if now I'm wanting to output all 3 objects, how should I get around to do it?

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I just discovered the power of .each() :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733314/jquery-loop-over-json-result-from-ajax-success

Answer (score 5):

type alert(JSON.stringify(data));

Answer (score 4):

alert returns `[object Object], [object Object], [object Object]` because you have array of 3 javascript objects and objects can't be just alerted as strings, you can use `console.log` to see the content of the object, just use `console.log` instead of `alert` and check the console of your browser

Answer (score 1):

The `alert(data)` is returning three objects because that is what JSON is.. **J**ava**s**cript **O**bject **N**otation.

It's returning an array objects, that's all its returning, and that's why it shows up the way it does.

If you want to see the results of such an array.. what each object contains, then you need to use `console.log()`:

```
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

what Sushanth said above

```
    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        alert(data[i].IDKey);
    }
```

If you are using IE, remember to get rid of or comment out the console.log() methods.
IE doesn't like them very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your output is [object, object] because you're actually returning an array of objects. In order to retrieve the contents of those objects, you'll have to iterate through each array and access each individual object contained.