# html ajax post method returning null value

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

how to send json from html to php using ajax post method? i refered to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955017/sending-json-to-php-using-ajax) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522564/ajax-success-function-returning-object-object) in order to get here but i have been getting null return value since, the rest of similar questions get me nowhere.

html(jquery ajax):

```
$('#unit1').change(function() {
var data = "";
  var selectedUnit1 = this.value;
  var dropDownNumber = "1";
  var postData = {"selectedUnit": selectedUnit1, "unitNumber": dropDownNumber};
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "ex02test.php",
            data: {data:postData},
            success: function(response){
                alert(response.title); // to test for return value, now it returns null, 
//hard-coding $unitTitle(example $unitTitle = 'hi'; in php file makes it display 'hi' so the php side is definitely working
                // data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                $('#txtHint').val(response[0].title);
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log(e.message);
            }
    });
$('#totalcost').val(valueFUnction());
});
```

php:

```
<?php
$jsonData=$_POST["data"];

$data = json_decode($jsonData);

$unitCode = $data->selectedUnit;

$dropDownNumber = $data->unitNumber;

$unitTitle = $dropDownNumber;
$unitFee = "10";

$reply->title = $unitTitle;
$reply->fee = $unitFee;

$jsonReply = json_encode($reply);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $jsonReply;
?>
```

Comment: Hi can you just see what is `alert(response)` giving ? Also , where did you declare `$reply` ?

Comment: $reply is declared on $reply->? i followed https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp
alert(response); does not work

Answer (score 0):

A first step to debug this would be to update your PHP file to something like this:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
die();
```

You can then see that there probably is no `data` key in the `$_POST` variable, but your JSON content is posted directly into the body of the POST.

In this case, I would expect you could just retrieve the values in PHP with something like:

```
$selectedUnit = $_POST["selectedUnit"];
```

But please check the output of the `var_dump()` to see exactly what is sent to the server.

Comment: so... how do i get the data in php?

Comment: just tried your suggestion for retrieving the value, the alert message does not work anymore haha... havent not tried the var_dump... may i know how to use it? tried to echo var dump into a div, but the div did not display any changes