# jQuery Ajax Callback for array result

Tags: jquery

I have following `jQuery Ajax` scenario in which a  webmethod returns a collection of strings.

1. The collection can be null
2. The collection can be non-null but zero records.
3. The collection has one or more records

The following code works fine. It uses [jQuery.isEmptyObject](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/). It is advised not to use `isEmptyObject()` when it is not a `Plain Object`.

How can we handle the result without using isEmptyObject() ?

Note: The ajax "result" is coming as "not plain".

Reference:

1. [Is object empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994201/is-object-empty)
2. [Javascript's hasOwnProperty() Method Is More Consistent Than The IN Operator](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1919-Javascript-s-hasOwnProperty-Method-Is-More-Consistent-Than-The-IN-Operator.htm)

**CODE**

```
//Callback Function
function displayResultForLog(result) 
{


if (result.hasOwnProperty("d")) 
{
    result = result.d
}


if ($.isPlainObject(result)) {
    alert('plain object');
}
else 
{
    alert('not plain');
}

if($.isEmptyObject(result))
{
    //Method returned null        
    $(requiredTable).append('No data found for the search criteria.');
}
else
{

    if (result.hasOwnProperty('length')) 
    {

        //Set the values in HTML
        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
        {
            var sentDate = result[i];
        }
    }

    else 
    {
      //Method returned non-null object; but there is no rows in that        
      $(requiredTable).append('No data found for the search criteria.');
    }

  }

 }

function setReportTable(receivedContext) {

var searchInput = '111';
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "ReportList.aspx/GetReportsSentWithinDates",
            data: '{"searchInput": "' + searchInput + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            context: receivedContext, //CONTEXT
            success: displayResultForLog

        }
        );
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present I am using the following. Any improvement suggestions?

```
 function displayResultForLog(result) 
 {
   if (result.hasOwnProperty("d")) {
       result = result.d
   }

if (result !== undefined && result != null )
{
    if (result.hasOwnProperty('length')) 
    {
        if (result.length >= 1) 
        {
            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                var sentDate = result[i];

            }
        }
        else 
        {
            $(requiredTable).append('Length is 0');
        }
    }

    else 
    {
        $(requiredTable).append('Length is not available.');
    }

}
else 
{
    $(requiredTable).append('Result is null.');
}
}
```

Reference for undefined is here [JavaScript undefined Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp)

> The undefined property indicates that a variable has not been assigned a value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if($.isEmptyObject(result))
```

would

```
if(typeof result !== 'undefined' && result.length < 1)
```

work?

Reference for undefined is here [JavaScript undefined Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp)

> The undefined property indicates that a variable has not been assigned a value.

Comment: Good point, I've amended by suggestion to check if the object isn't undefined.

Comment: Is it `!== "undefined"` or `!== undefined`?

Comment: Good catch, in this case, 'undefined' is what we should be looking for