# Cannot render events from JSON feed

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Updated:

Many thanks for your reply, I now have this code:

```
  success: function (data) {

      $.each(data, function (id, event)

      var test = data.approved
      if (test == "1") {
          alert('approved')
      }

      );
  }
```

Here is the sample of my JSON:

{"id":"174","title":"John Smith","start":"2013-04-03 00:00:00","end":"2013-04-05 00:00:00","fullname":"John Smith","approved":"1"},
{"id":"175","title":"John Smith","start":"2012-12-25 00:00:00","end":"2012-12-27 00:00:00","fullname":"John Smith","approved":"0"},
{"id":"176","title":"John Smith","start":"2012-12-28 00:00:00","end":"2012-12-28 00:00:00","fullname":"John Smith","approved":"1"},
{"id":"177","title":"John Smith","start":"2012-12-29 00:00:00","end":"2012-12-29 00:00:00","fullname":"John Smith","approved":"0"},
{"id":"178","title":"John Smith","start":"2012-12-21 00:00:00","end":"2012-12-22 00:00:00","fullname":"John Smith","approved":"1"}

Could you please advise as to how I can get the approved alert if the event has been approved in the JSON?

Many thanks once again

Comment: What browser? Most have a debug view (chrome->CTRL+SHFT+J, IE->F12, FF->CTRL+SHFT+K, etc.) where you can view network traffic and see what's returned.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes, firebug returns this: {"id":"76","title":"John Smith","start":"2012-12-29 00:00:00","end":"2012-12-29 00:00:00","fullname":"John Smith","approved":"1"}

Comment: I would like to validate the approved field for each event and add a class name if its '1'

Comment: Where does event get defined?

Comment: I dont think it does, I've edited my post and added the full code, the php JSON code is towards the bottom.

Comment: You're missing an opening { after the $.each function

Comment: I updated my response below.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the data like this -

```
success: function(data) {    
    var event = data.approved;
    if(event == "1") {
        // do stuff 
    }
}
```

Here is the code that should work -

```
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
        $.each(this, function(k, v) {
            if((k == 'approved') && (v == '1')) {
                alert('approved!')
            } 
        });
    });
}
```

Have a look at this [jQuery loop over JSON result from AJAX Success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733314/jquery-loop-over-json-result-from-ajax-success)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So my eventSources should look like this:       'eventSources: [

        // your event source
        {
            url: 'json-events.php',
            type: 'POST',
            error: function(data) {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!' + data.msge);
            },
   success: function(data) {    
    var event = data.approved;
    if(event == "1") {
       alert('approved'); // do stuff 
    else{
      alert('uapproved'); // do stuff 
    }
}
 
        }

      

    ]'

Comment: Something like this:
 
      if(event == "1") {
 event.title = event.title + "approved";
     event.className = "approved";
   } else{
   event.title = event.title + "awaiting approval";
       event.className = "unapproved";
   
    }         

However I get event udefined error.

Comment: Can someone also tell me how to add a comment with formatted code? thanks

Comment: You cannot, you have to edit your original post. I based my answer on the JSON response that you put in your comment above.

Comment: Anymore ideas folks? still stuck with this.

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon after data.title

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, I cant seem to pass an ID to the click function which is causing the problem. Any ideas? Thankyou

Comment: Shouldn't this var eventid = calEvent.id; be var eventid = calEvent.eventid; ?

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I've edited my code if you could confirm I am on the right path that would be great.

Comment: Without being able to connect to your JSON source it would appear that you are on the right path.