# Parsing a JSON object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, object

here is an example of the JSON string:

```
[{"Description":"Administrators can do everything on the site","Id":"381ede0e-3bc1-4d71-83d8-bbb62a3b8aaa","Name":"Admin"},{"Description":"Technical users with limited permissions a","Id":"7a632af6-214b-4a8e-a3f8-9c0aafae2645","Name":"Technical"}]
```

here is my script so far:

```
 //Get Users Roles:
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetAUsersRegisteredRoles")' + '/' + selectedUser, function (json) {
                console.log('1:');
                console.log(json);

                //Parse JSON
                $.each(json, function () {
                    $.each(this, function (k, v) {
                        alert(v.Id + v.Name +v.Description);
                    })
                });
            });
```

I know I am doing something wrong with the way that I am parsing it?
Im sure its just something silly.

Here is the view of the json array in the console:
[image]

When I run it in the browser my alert popup comes 6 times and says `NaN`

I looked at: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733314/jquery-loop-over-json-result-from-ajax-success) which helped me get to where I am now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you don't need the second loop

```
$.each(json, function (k, v) {
    alert(v.Id + v.Name + v.Description);
});
```

Comment: Oh ok I see. the each already splits up each element. I only need to lop through the sub elements.

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON is an array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "Description": "Administrators can do everything on the site",
        "Id": "381ede0e-3bc1-4d71-83d8-bbb62a3b8aaa",
        "Name": "Admin"
    },
    {
        "Description": "Technical users with limited permissions a",
        "Id": "7a632af6-214b-4a8e-a3f8-9c0aafae2645",
        "Name": "Technical"
    }
]
```

You only need to iterate over the top level:

```
$.each(json, function (k, v) {
    console.log(v.Id, v.Name, v.Description);
});
```

PS: it often helps if you look directly at pretty-printed JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You're enumerating the elements in the list, then the properties of each element. One loop should suffice:

```
$.each(json, function () {
    alert(this.Id + this.Name +this.Description);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's fine. Just wrap `this` with `$` to jquerify it like $(this).

Here is the example:

```
var json = [
    {
        "Description":"Administrators can do everything on the site",
        "Id":"381ede0e-3bc1-4d71-83d8-bbb62a3b8aaa",
        "Name":"Admin"
    },
    {
        "Description":"Technical users with limited permissions a",
        "Id":"7a632af6-214b-4a8e-a3f8-9c0aafae2645",
        "Name":"Technical"
    }
];

$.each(json, function () {
    $.each($(this), function (k, v) { // this ==> $(this) in this line
        alert(v.Id + v.Name +v.Description);
    })
});
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/xL7jm/

or dont do the second loop, because you have reference of the entire object in the first loop only. like:

```
$.each(json, function (k, v) {
    // Here v is that object each time of the loop
    alert(v.Id + v.Name +v.Description);
});
```

Jsfiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/xL7jm/1/