# Is there a getJSON sucess function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a getJSON function that looks like below:

```
$.getJSON("jsonStats.php?action=segment", function(json) {
    //Loop over each of the values in the jSON response to make the table.
        var tableSegments = '',
            counter = 1;
        $.each(json, function(key, value) {
                tableSegments += '<tr>';
                    tableSegments += '<td></td>';
                    tableSegments += '<td>'+counter+'</td>';
                    tableSegments += '<td>'+value['name']+'</td>';
                    tableSegments += '<td>'+value['y']+'</td>';
                tableSegments += '</tr>';
            counter++;
        });

        $('#segmentTable').empty().append(tableSegments);   
});
```

The issue that I am running into is that its running the each statement/creating the table before it even gets the data. Is there a way to make it wait until it actually has the jSON data before doing that part?

Comment: _"... before it even gets the data"_, that's not true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `done` callback ([jquery.getjson reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/))  :

```
$.getJSON('jsonStats.php?action=segment')
.done(function(json)
{
    //Loop over each of the values in the jSON response to make the table.
    var tableSegments = '',
        counter = 1;

    $.each(json, function(key, value)
    {
        tableSegments += '<tr>';
        tableSegments += '<td></td>';
        tableSegments += '<td>'+counter+'</td>';
        tableSegments += '<td>'+value['name']+'</td>';
        tableSegments += '<td>'+value['y']+'</td>';
        tableSegments += '</tr>';
        counter++;
    });

    $('#segmentTable').empty().append(tableSegments);   
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error)
{
    var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
    console.log( 'Request Failed: ' + err );
});
```

Comment: The values from the `$.each` just print undefined even though the data is there when I log it

Comment: @SBB Please look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733314/jquery-loop-over-json-result-from-ajax-success

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out..

```
value['name'] and value['y']
```

need to be `value[0]` and `value[1]`

I had the headers as `text/javascript` on accident this morning so the response was an object, changed it to `application/json` and thats what made those values change.

Comment: `$.getJSON` ignores the `Content-type` header, I don't think that has anything to do with it. It sounds like you changed the format of the array in the PHP.