# jQuery nested .each loop over JSON success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Referencing this post
[jQuery loop over JSON result from AJAX Success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733314/jquery-loop-over-json-result-from-ajax-success)

JSON being returned (as seen in Firebug):

```
[
   {"NUMBER":"N02939667","BARCODE":"B000615994","LOAD_FK":"7813","CRO":"VONS"},
   {"NUMBER":"N02939667","BARCODE":"B000607696","LOAD_FK":"8875","CRO":"VONS"}
]
```

My AJAX with the nested .each functions:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_shipment_by_nnumber.php",
        data: searchItemDataString,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(g){
            if ($.isEmptyObject(g[0].LOAD_FK)){
                //validate json returned
            }else{
                  $('.BGresults').empty();
                  $.each(g, function() {
                      $.each(this, function(k, v) {
                          var result = '<strong>     ' + searchItem + ':  (' + v.BARCODE + ') (Reg ID = ' + v.LOAD_FK + ')  (' + v.CRO + ')</strong><br>';
                          $('.BGresults').append(result);
                      });
                  });                   
             };
         }
    })
```

My output is iterating over each k/v pair and not finding the value. I'm guessing because I have two objects each with 5 k/v pairs that I get get 10 outputs. I've looked at similar posts on s.o. but I'm just not seeing the answer that makes sense to me. Can someone point out my mistakes. Thanks.

```
N02939667.1-1: (undefined) (Reg ID = undefined) (undefined)
N02939667.1-1: (undefined) (Reg ID = undefined) (undefined)
N02939667.1-1: (undefined) (Reg ID = undefined) (undefined)
N02939667.1-1: (undefined) (Reg ID = undefined) (undefined)
N02939667.1-1: (undefined) (Reg ID = undefined) (undefined)
N02939667.1-1: (undefined) (Reg ID = undefined) (undefined)
N02939667.1-1: (undefined) (Reg ID = undefined) (undefined)
N02939667.1-1: (undefined) (Reg ID = undefined) (undefined)
N02939667.1-1: (undefined) (Reg ID = undefined) (undefined)
N02939667.1-1: (undefined) (Reg ID = undefined) (undefined)
```

Comment: The `v` in your second each is the value and not an object.  Your second `$.each()` is looping over the object that was passed in. So the values of `k` and `v` would be `k = "NUMBER", v = "N02939667" then k = "BARCODE", v = "B000615994", etc...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your current code to work, you need to reference the `$(this)` in your second nested loop instead of `this`.  Also, you'll notice in my fiddle I hardcoded the value of `searchItem` as you didn't provide it in your example.

[fiddle with simulated data](http://jsfiddle.net/bAmRR/)

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_shipment_by_nnumber.php",
        data: searchItemDataString,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(g){
            if ($.isEmptyObject(g[0].LOAD_FK)){
                //validate json returned
            }else{
                  $('.BGresults').empty();
                  $.each(g, function() {
                      $.each($(this), function(k, v) {
                          var result = '<strong>     ' + searchItem + ':  (' + v.BARCODE + ') (Reg ID = ' + v.LOAD_FK + ')  (' + v.CRO + ')</strong><br>';
                          $('.BGresults').append(result);
                      });
                  });                   
             };
         }
    })
```

Comment: I just looked up this VS $(this), makes more sense to me now.

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = [
   {"NUMBER":"N02939667","BARCODE":"B000615994","LOAD_FK":"7813","CRO":"VONS"},
   {"NUMBER":"N02939667","BARCODE":"B000607696","LOAD_FK":"8875","CRO":"VONS"}
];

$.each(data, function() { 
    var output = [];

    $.each(this, function(k, v) {
       output.push(k, v);
    });

    console.log(output.join(' '));

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this Example:

```
data = [
       {"NUMBER":"N02939667","BARCODE":"B000615994","LOAD_FK":"7813","CRO":"VONS"},
       {"NUMBER":"N02939667","BARCODE":"B000607696","LOAD_FK":"8875","CRO":"VONS"}
       ]

//for each value in data => this ("this" is a variable containing an element of data)
$.each(data, function(){   //in this function you can access "this", and element of data
    $.each(this, function(k,v){  //inner loop iterated over the key-value pairs of "this"
        console.log(k +"==="+v);
        })
});
```

this outputs:

```
NUMBER===N02939667 
BARCODE===B000615994 
LOAD_FK===7813 
CRO===VONS 
NUMBER===N02939667 
BARCODE===B000607696 
LOAD_FK===8875 
CRO===VONS
```

That is `k` takes the value of each key in the JSON object, and `v` takes the corresponding value. What you actually seem want to do is get a specific value from the JSON object and stick it in some HTML. Do that like so:

```
$.each(data, function(){  
    var result = '<strong>     ' + searchItem + ':  (' + this.BARCODE + ') (Reg ID = ' + this.LOAD_FK + ')  (' + this.CRO + ')</strong><br>';
    $('.BGresults').append(result);
});
```

use `this.key` to access the given value for that key in the JSON object.

Comment: I'm glad you posted using this with one .each to contrast with @rooster answer. Both ways worked and made it easier for me to see the difference.