# encode PHP JSON data in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am getting JSON encoded data after ajax call to PHP :

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"4",
      "name":"Kg",
      "vital_sign_list_id":"3",
      "created":"2016-03-01 18:52:27",
      "modiefied":"2016-03-01 18:52:27"
   },
   {  
      "id":"5",
      "name":"Pound",
      "vital_sign_list_id":"3",
      "created":"2016-03-01 18:52:27",
      "modiefied":"2016-03-01 18:52:27"
   }
]
```

There are two datas, and I want to decode using loop and use data using **jquery**. How can I achieve it?

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: I think you are mixing up en-/ and decode. What you have here is *encoded* json. And if you want to use it with PHP you probably want to *decode* it. (And no idea what that JQuery should do here)

Comment: Sorry all for it. I edited it!!

Comment: Do you now want to decode it with PHP or JQuery now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery loop over JSON result from AJAX Success?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733314/jquery-loop-over-json-result-from-ajax-success)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    json = '[{"id":"4","name":"Kg","vital_sign_list_id":"3","created":"2016-03-01 18:52:27","modiefied":"2016-03-01 18:52:27"}, {"id":"5","name":"Pound","vital_sign_list_id":"3","created":"2016-03-01 18:52:27","modiefied":"2016-03-01 18:52:27"}]';
    var obj = $.parseJSON( json);
    $.each(obj, function(index, val){
       alert(val.name);
       //you can access other data by using val.id, val.created etc
    });
</script>
```

for more detail have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/ and  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```js
var data = [{"id":"4","name":"Kg","vital_sign_list_id":"3","created":"2016-03-01 18:52:27","modiefied":"2016-03-01 18:52:27"}, {"id":"5","name":"Pound","vital_sign_list_id":"3","created":"2016-03-01 18:52:27","modiefied":"2016-03-01 18:52:27"}];



for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++){
  
  console.log("ID "+ i +": "+ data[i].id);
  console.log("Name "+ i +": "+ data[i].name);
  console.log("Vital "+ i +": "+ data[i].vital_sign_list_id);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
json_encode(jsonArrVar);
```

use this in your json php file to encode your json data.
and in jquery parse it using json.parse or eval function.