# save table records in associative array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, ajax

I have an associative array. After I select my records from my table (with two columns: objName,objCost), I want to save them in my array like this:

```
array(
      'objName'=>$row['objName'],
      'objCost'=>$row['objCost']
)
```

How should I do this?

This is my code:

```
$output = '';
$arr = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM obj WHERE objName LIKE '%" . $_POST["search"] . "%'";
$result = $db->query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if ($result->rowCount() != 0) {
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   //here i should insert my rows into my array        
}
$json_arr = json_encode($arr,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo $json_arr;
} else {
echo 'Data Not Found';
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for guidance with this and other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code,

```
$arr[] = ['objName'=>$row['objName'],'objCost'=>$row['objCost']];
```

Then you can encode the array and pick up the object on the other side with javascript or php. Which ever suits you

```
json_encode($arr);
```

In you Ajax success, get the objects and use the values as you deem fit

```
success: function (data) {data = JSON.parse(data); 

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    alert(data[i].objName);
   }
}
```

see [jQuery loop over JSON result from AJAX Success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733314/jquery-loop-over-json-result-from-ajax-success) on how to loop through your results in jquery

Comment: actually i wanna use this in a live search using ajax.i try ur code.but it returns just one record

Comment: This has to do with the way you are fetching. Have you tried to Fetch All?

Comment: i tried this way :$arr[$row['objName']] = $row['objCost'];
the output is this: Object {benz: 11111, lamborgini: 400}

Comment: the way you told has this output:
    Object {objName: "benz", objCost: 11111}

Comment: see, you're to fetch all results and not just on with while ($row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { $arr[] = ['objName'=>$row['objName'],'objCost'=>$row['objCost']]; json_encode($arr); } You now have to pick up the object in your ajax javascript result. Can i see that code?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function () { $('#s').keyup(function () {var txt = $(this).val();if (txt != '') {$.ajax({url: "index.php",method: "post",data: {search: txt},dataType: "json",success: function (data) {$('#object').append($('<option>',{value:1, text:'One'}));
                                                                console.log(data);}}); }else{$("#result").html('');} }); });</script>

Comment: on success, get the objects and use them eg: success: function (data) {data = JSON.parse(data);                            }

Comment: sorry.i'm beginner.how can I use it?for example I want to get objName

Comment: i just added an example to my answer above

Comment: i tried this:console.log(data);
                                                                data = JSON.parse(data);
                                                                console.log(data);
the output:
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
VM2973:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1(…)

Comment: it's ok now. i used console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
thanks alot for ur help