# Geting first 10 rows from a JSON file

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have this code and i would like to get the first ten rows from the file on page load. Then i need to load 10 more by clickinng on the button.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'drzave-brojevi.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (json) {
        var inHTML = '<table id="predmeti" class="display"><thead><tr><th>Broj</th><th>Države</th><th>Odabir</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
        $.each(json, function (i, k) {

            inHTML += '<tr><td>' + k + "</td><td>" + i + '</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="drzava_odabir" value="' + i + '"></td></tr>';

        });
        inHTML += '</tbody></table>';
        $('#cilj')[0].innerHTML = inHTML;
    }
});
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you provide the rest of the code, connected to this snippet? as it looks to be out of the rest of the context.

Comment: All you have defined is a goal....but not any specific code related problem associated with attaining that goal. Take some time to read [ask]

Comment: {
"Afganistan":"+93",
"Albanija":"+355",
"Alžir":"+213",
"Andora":"+376",
"Angola":"+244",
"Antigva i Barbuda":"+1 (268)",
"Argentina":"+54",
"Armenija":"+374",
"Australija":"+61",
"Austrija":"+43",
"Azerbajdžan":"+994",
"Bahami":"+1 (24)",
"Bahrein":"+973",
"Bangladeš":"+880"
}

Comment: You can add for loop and give it limit by 10.

Comment: [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733314/jquery-loop-over-json-result-from-ajax-success?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: The code i provided works fine for me but i got the whole JSON file. I need just get the first 10 rows and show it as {country : call number : checkbox}.