# How to get values of child element on Array multiple dimension of JSON by Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

i have issued with array JSON.
i have try many time but didn't work.

//i put my code to there, kindly help me debug it.

the string json

```
> {"resultUser":[{"username":"quyennv","email":"quyencl@hotmail.com","userlevel":0,"datecreate":"20/03/2019
> 12:00:00
> AM","status":1},{"username":"sample","email":"sameple@hotmail.com","userlevel":1,"datecreate":"20/03/2019
> 12:00:00 AM","status":1}]}
```

and here is code for view element in array

```js
var datax = {"resultUser":[{"username":"quyennv","email":"quyencl@hotmail.com","userlevel":0,"datecreate":"20/03/2019 12:00:00 AM","status":1},{"username":"sample","email":"sameple@hotmail.com","userlevel":1,"datecreate":"20/03/2019 12:00:00 AM","status":1}]};

var userTbl = $('#listUser tbody').empty();                  
$.each(datax.resultUser,function (index) {  
    index += 1;
    userTbl.append('<tr><td>' + this.username + '</td><td>'  
        + this.email + '</td><td>' + this.userlevel + '</td><td>'  
        + this.datecreate + '</td><td>' + this.status + '</td></tr>');  

});
```

```css
table,td{
 border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<table id="listUser">
<thead ><tr><td>Username</td><td>Email</td><td>User Level</td><td>Date Created</td><td>User status</td></tr></thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

kindly help me solve this issue. thanks a lot

=====
Updated.
i need more details element inside the each loop
change **datax** to **datax.resultUser**

Comment: $.each(datax.resultUser, function (index) {  
    index += 1;
    userTbl.append('<tr><td>' + this.username + '</td><td>'  
        + this.email + '</td><td>' + this.userlevel + '</td><td>'  
        + this.datecreate + '</td><td>' + this.status + '</td></tr>');  

});

Comment: Accessing aarray in object issue in Ur case

Comment: thanks for your response. im very thank :D

Answer (score 0):

Change **data** to **datax.resultUser** in $.each to loop through array of resultUser

```js
var datax = {"resultUser":[{"username":"quyennv","email":"quyencl@hotmail.com","userlevel":0,"datecreate":"20/03/2019 12:00:00 AM","status":1},{"username":"sample","email":"sameple@hotmail.com","userlevel":1,"datecreate":"20/03/2019 12:00:00 AM","status":1}]};

var userTbl = $('#listUser tbody').empty();                  
$.each(datax.resultUser,function (index) {  
    index += 1;
    userTbl.append('<tr><td>' + this.username + '</td><td>'  
        + this.email + '</td><td>' + this.userlevel + '</td><td>'  
        + this.datecreate + '</td><td>' + this.status + '</td></tr>');  

});
```

```css
table,td{
 border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<table id="listUser">
<thead ><tr><td>Username</td><td>Email</td><td>User Level</td><td>Date Created</td><td>User status</td></tr></thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: If my post helped to resolve your issue, please mark it as answer

Comment: Hi guy, i have used your code but still issue as the picture, can you let me know why the jquery do running or running withou responding for the each loop

https://i.imgur.com/RJ49jf6.png

Comment: Picture is not clear but seems to be path issue with 404 not found

Comment: the 404 is talking about images for avatar. not releated about jquery

Comment: For your Ajax request , add     dataType: 'json'

Comment: Refer this link -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733314/jquery-loop-over-json-result-from-ajax-success

Comment: I think the link which I have shared helped you.. now you can mark my post as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.each(datax.resultUser, function (index) { index += 1; 
 userTbl.append('<tr><td>' + this.username + '</td><td>' + 
 this.email + '</td><td>' + this.userlevel + '</td><td>' + 
 this.datecreate + '</td><td>' + this.status + '</td></tr>'); });
```

data.resultUser only array you have to itreate that only