# How can i show recived multiple json data in a laravel blade file

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

(Route File)

```php
Route::post('/report/collectorSearch','reportController@collectorSearch');
```

(blade file)
ajax code

```js
        $('#collector_name').change(function(event) {
            /* Act on the event */
            var collector_id = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '{{URL::to("/report/collectorSearch")}}',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 
                    collector_id:collector_id,
                    _token: $('#Productsignup_token').val() 
                },
                dataType:'json',

                success:function(CollectorResponse){
                        console.log(CollectorResponse);

                    }
                })

        });
```

controller

```php
  public function collectorSearch(Request $request){

        $getCollector_id = $request->collector_id;

        if ($getCollector_id) {
            $searchs = sellproduct::where('collector_id',$getCollector_id)->get();
            return response()->json($searchs);

        }
    }
```

Comment: use loop and append data into html using JQuery.....Please specify the issue you are facing

Comment: i am reciving json data but how i can use foreach in json data , it the main issu for me

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733314/jquery-loop-over-json-result-from-ajax-success

Comment: actually i can not execute the theroy